# Formula for finding date date when value exceeds given value within defined dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Link 1 is a sample of "Tab1" as described below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5UuH.jpg)
Tab1 has:

- Column A with each row identified by a specific date in sequence
- Column AE shows a stock price for each day

[Link 2 is sample of "Tab2" as described below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzycz.jpg)
Tab2 has:

- Column C has stock purchase and sale dates in sequence (C2 is purchase date, C3 is sale date, etc.)
- Column I has key stock sale trigger prices, associated with each date from column C

I need a formula to put into Tab2 that will look at Tab1 between the purchase and sale dates from Tab2 column C to return the earliest date from Tab1 column A when the value on Tab1 column AE exceeds or is equal to the value identified in Tab2 Column I.  Hopefully this is clear enough, I can try to paste a sample if this helps.

Comment: MINIFS not working for you ...?

Comment: sample would be excellent

Comment: Jeeped, I see the MINFS function was created in 2016, it seems the version of excel (employer’s computer) is too old to have this function, is there an array formula that can be used?